# Radio buttons submitting no values

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

This seems (and should be) simple, but I have no idea why the values for my radio buttons appear empty

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="action_page.php">

<table>
<tr>
<th>Intermediate</th><th>Advanced</th><th>No selection</th>
</tr>

<tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label for="td1">1. Bash</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="td1" id="td1" value="BashInter"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="td1"  value="BashAdv"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="td1" value="" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label for="td1">2. C</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="td2" id="td2" value="CInter"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="td2"  value="CAdv"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="td2" value="" /></td>
    </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label for="td1">3. C++</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="td3" id="td3" value="C++Inter"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="td3"  value="C++Adv"/>
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="td3" value="" /></td>
    </tr></table>


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click "Submit", the form-data will be sent to a page called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If run on W3Schools' (ugh) [server](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit), it correctly outputs the input.
e.g.

> td1=BashInter&td2=CAdv&td3=

However, my server, for `print_r($_POST);` returns

> [td1] => [td2] => [td3] =>

regardless of what is selected.

Looking at the HTTP headers confirms that nothing is being sent.

All other aspects of the form correctly send their values.

[image: radio values]

I have tried a number of variants in relation to the values, but nothing has altered the fact that no data actually appears to be sent by the radio buttons.

Comment: @billyonecan That's not the real form (which is a couple of thousand lines long). I'm using POST with the real one.

Comment: Added post method to sample code. Note that everything other than the radio buttons are correctly sending data.

Comment: so the radios are posted, but their values are empty strings? are you sure you don't have anything which is selecting the last option in each group?

Comment: @billyonecan I... don't think so. I just gave the last option a sample string "test", just to make sure; but regardless of selection, still appear to be empty

Comment: are you sure you're not overriding the values somewhere? check the entire form for `name="td1"` etc.

Comment: @billyonecan I finally tracked down the culprit. Of all the possible causes - it was Sessionstorage! How sessionstorage could cause this problem, why sessionstorage would cause this problem, and what I can do to stop sessionstorage from causing this problem I've yet to determine :/ I didn't bother mentioning sessionstorage in the question because I couldn't see how it would be relevant (still don't!)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified that your form must be send as a POST one, so used method is defaulted to GET.

Try with

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Last radio button of every set has been kept empty and has black value.**

Which means `<input type="radio"  name="td3" value="" />` needs to be  replaced with `<input type="radio"  name="td3" value="Some value 3" />`

So in case you are selecting last radio button from every set then obviously it wont return anything.

Apart from this there is not other problem as long as your HTML code is concerned. If you still face any problem please upload your PHP code as well.

I also suggest to give some some meaningful label to each radio.

**Here is the code you may try**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="action_page.php">

<table>
<tr>
<th>Intermediate</th><th>Advanced</th><th>No selection</th>
</tr>

<tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label for="td1">1. Bash</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="td1" id="td1" value="BashInter"/> BashInter
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="td1"  value="BashAdv"/> BashAdv
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="td1" value="Some value 1" /> Some value 1</td>
    </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label for="td1">2. C</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="td2" id="td2" value="CInter"/> CInter
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="td2"  value="CAdv"/> CAdv
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="td2" value="Some value 2" /> Some value 2</td>
    </tr><tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <label for="td1">3. C++</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="td3" id="td3" value="C++Inter"/> C++Inter
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="td3"  value="C++Adv"/> C++Adv
        </td>
        <td><input type="radio"  name="td3" value="Some value 3" /> Some value 3</td>
    </tr></table>


<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

<p>If you click "Submit", the form-data will be sent to a page called "action_page.php".</p>

</body>
</html>
```